# Manage memory error working with a very large matrix in Python

Tags: python, nlp, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis, word-embedding

I am using the following code to create word embeddings and then calculate cosine similarity

```
             model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-mean-tokens')
             sen_embeddings = model.encode(df)

             sen_embeddings = np.array(sen_embeddings)
             cosine_sim_matrix = cosine_similarity(sen_embeddings)
```

My data had 100k rows. Hence cosine_sim_matrix is a 100k by 100k matrix and has a size of ~37GB. Now I need to create a linkage matrix for clustering

```
             linkage_matrix = linkage(1 - cosine_sim_matrix , method='complete')
```

I get an error because of the huge size of the matrix. I cannot split the data into smaller datasets. What other ways can we get this done?